# Алгоритм для нахождения минимального и максимального количества ребер

Tags: математика, графы

Как можно найти минимальное и максимальное количество ребер у неориентированного графа с N вершинами и K связными компонентами, если в графе есть один цикл

Answer (score 0):

Вспоминаете определение дерева. Из единственного цикла удаляете любое ребро. Получаете дерево. Задача сведена к лесу из `K` деревьев и `N` вершин. Вспоминаете как связаны ребра и вершины в одном дереве, суммируете по деревьям, добавляете обратно удалённое ребро. Удивляетесь как просто.